# CARLA Installation: Error occurs when running 'make PythonAPI'

Tags: installation, carla

CARLA version: 0.9.14
Platform/OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5
Python version: 3.7.6
Virtual environment: py3_3.8.10
Problem you have experienced: Error occurs when running 'make PythonAPI'
What you expected to happen: BuildPythonAPI.sh: Success!
Steps to reproduce: using 'build with source' method to build CARLA (provided at https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.14/build_linux/), after setting Unreal Engine environment variable, do 'make PythonAPI' step, and then error occurs in stage 'BuildPythonAPI.sh: Building Python API for Python 3.'
Other information (documentation you consulted, workarounds you tried):
the last part of output information in terminal is attached below\

---

BuildOSM2ODR.sh: Success!
Using clang-10 as the CARLA compiler.
BuildPythonAPI.sh: Building Python API for Python 3.
setup.py:37: DeprecationWarning: distro.linux_distribution() is deprecated. It should only be used as a compatibility shim with Python's platform.linux_distribution(). Please use distro.id(), distro.version() and distro.name() instead.
linux_distro = distro.linux_distribution()[0]
compiling:

source/libcarla/libcarla.cpp
/home/bld/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:689: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: As setuptools moves its configuration towards pyproject.toml,
setuptools.config.parse_configuration became deprecated.
For the time being, you can use the setuptools.config.setupcfg module
to access a backward compatible API, but this module is provisional
and might be removed in the future.

parse_configuration(self, self.command_options,
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", 
line 163, in setup(
File "/home/bld/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/init.py", 
line 160, in setup
_install_setup_requires(attrs)
File "/home/bld/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/init.py", 
line 153, in _install_setup_requires
dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
File "/home/bld/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", 
line 689, in parse_config_files
parse_configuration(self, self.command_options,
File "/home/bld/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/init.py", 
line 29, in _wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bld/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py", 
line 187, in parse_configuration
distribution._referenced_files.update(
AttributeError: 'MinimalDistribution' object has no attribute '_referenced_files'
make: *** [Util/BuildTools/Linux.mk:87: PythonAPI] Error 1

---

I expected the stage output should be 'BuildPythonAPI.sh: Success!', but an error came. I had also add argument ' make PythonAPI ARGS="--python-version=3.7" '(or version=3.8, had tried as well), still came with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved. Error comes because the virtual environment runs with python 3.8. Problem can be solved by switching to the virtual environment with python 3.7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).